# Unable to start the Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2013, emulation, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I've seen this error several times. Each time I google deeply and finally made me reinstall my windows and all stuffs. Please help, I don't want to reinstall everything again. The error is:

```
Windows Phone Emulator

Unable to start the Windows Phone Emulator

Windows Phone Emulator is unable to start because 
the hypervisor is not running. The likely cause is
that hardware-assisted virtualization is not enabled.

Check your computer's BIOS to ensure that hardware-
assisted virtualization and hardware-assisted data 
execution features are enabled.
```

[image: Unable to start the Windows Phone Emulator]

But yesterday I debugged really normally on Windows Phone using Emulator and I really sure
 **I've turned on Virtualization in BIOS** and also in **Turn Windows features on or off** :
[image: Turned on all]

Sometimes when I hit f5 the IDE come with another error: 0x80131500
[image]

My PC: windows 8.1 ultimate 64b, 4gb ram, i3, Visual Studio 2013 RC3

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Finally after struggling all day, I solved it ^^
I post the solution here so that somebody don't have to waste time just like me to solve such a silly error!

1. Just simple **disable Hyper-V** option in Turn Windows features on or off
   (you could open this by hit the combination Windows + S, this will open the search box, then type "Turn Windows features on or off"
2. **restart your PC**
3. **enable the Hyper-V** option by using the same way as step 1.

Enjoy coding :D

Comment: This works like charm - thank you very much, you saved me lots of nerves after I was searching for a solution the whole morning :)

Comment: This is indeed the only working solution. Thanks for trying it first! Its a shame such info is nowhere to be found in MSFT own support forums.

Comment: Thanks! Although that should've been my first try... it's a Windows environment after all lol

Comment: You are genius! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the best wishes.

Comment: Hasn't worked for me.  After following exact steps and restarting, I got 2 errors (1) "You do not have permissions to modify internal Hyper-V network adapter settings, which are required to run the emulator" [Retry/Close].  Hitting retry stareted the emulator but then immediatelly error (2) "An OpenGL error has occured: Failed to read remote PID!.  The emulator will shut down."

Answer (score 5):

If the accepted answer doesn't work for you - as it unfortunately did not for me - also be sure to enable Data Execution Prevention (DEP) in your BIOS.

The article below outlines what BIOS settings to enable for Hyper-V:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

In my case, I had hardware-assisted virtualization enabled in the BIOS, but not data execution prevention (DEP). I also had Hyper-V enabled via Windows Features. After enabling DEP in the BIOS, I was able to run the Windows phone emulator.

Answer (score 4):

CMD with admin rights:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

and reboot.