# The Windows phone Emulator couldn't start

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, emulation, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am beginner in windows phone, and I have installed Windows phone SDK 8.0.   I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 along with OS Windows 10.

I have created new demo Windows phone project. And now whenever I am going to execute the emulator it's showing me an error like this:

[image: Error message when executing the Emulator]

I have made some R&D and already enabled the hyper-v mode from BIOS settings. But i am still getting this error.

Please help me out this situation.

Looking Forward to you guys..
Advanced Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the error message?  It gives some suggestions as to why it didn't start.  Try googling on those.

Comment: @Tim I have gone through that more information link. And the hyper-v mode is also enabled. And again it was saying the same error. That's why i asked this question.

Comment: You should include that information in your question - otherwise folks will assume that you haven't done any research.

Comment: Ok. Thanks tim for the update. I will update my question.

Comment: Now i am getting this error : 0x80131500

Comment: I had a similar error, though it was in a virtual machine. Check out the accepted answer here, which might give you some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35716492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Windows OS greater than Windows 8 OS does not support the Windows Phone 8 SDK to run on the Visual Studio 2012. You cannot run Emulator as well so better you should use a stable Windows 8 version for WP8 development. This is the statement right from Microsoft Support

**After you will upgrade your OS to any higher version then Windows 8, you cannot run Windows Phone 8 Emulator in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.**

For more reference see [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2864215)

Comment: The referenced article says to install VS 2012 Update 3, not that it can't be done.

Comment: In Symptoms: "After you upgrade your computer to Windows 8.1 Preview, you cannot run Windows Phone 8 Software Development Kit (SDK) emulator (XDE.exe) in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012."  Resolution: "To resolve this issue, install Visual Studio 2012 Update 3."  Nothing in there about not being able to run the Windows Phone 8.0 emulator in Windows 10.

Comment: But you can install and check if you want. I am also using the Windows 10 OS and not able to execute the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.

Comment: And regarding the VS 2012 Update 3. If you have installed VS 2012 Update 5 then you can't install VS 2012 Update 3. For that you have to uninstall Update 5.