# Visual Studio 2015 x86 emulator not running

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, haxm

I had issues when starting x86 emulator.  It was complaining that HAXM is not installed even though Android SDK manager shows it checked.  Then I found that I have to run intelhaxm-androd.exe located in my android-sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager.

I did that and it installed without any issues.  I restarted VS2015 and tried running my x86 emulator again but got "Permission denied" error as per screenshot.
[image]

Then I changed permission to Full permission on the file in screenshot above and try starting the emulator again but got message that "hypervisor is not running":
[image]

UPDATE:
Then I found link explaining how to enable Hyper-V using "Turn Windows Features on/off" as per link [Unable to start the Windows Phone Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26070567/656243)

However, after restarting my machine and VS and trying to run Visual Studio Emulator, I ended up with following errors
[image]

Hitting Retry in image above started the emulator but with this error:
[image]

Comment: What are the permissions on that file?

Comment: I set to Full permissions on that file but then got error as in the update above "The emulator is unable to start because the hypervisor is not running".  Thanks

Comment: This question targets the Windows Phone Emulator, but is effectively the same problem:   http://stackoverflow.com/q/26070567/656243

Comment: Thanks Lynn, I followed the steps as per answer in the link you provided.  That seem to take me step further but with new issues :(

Comment: Oh wow... the plot thickens...